# A piecewise function with fractions and without tiny text

Tags: align, cases

I would like to create a piecewise function which includes fractions.
But the solutions I have found so far squish the fractions in to tiny
text that is nearly illegible.

The `cases` environment results in tiny text and only allows for
one alignment character.

```
\begin{align}
    E(r) &=
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2} & \quad \text{if} \quad r > 0 \\
        0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{align}
```

The `array` environment allows for multiple alignment characters
but the text is still tiny.

```
\begin{align}
    E(r) &=
    \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2} & \quad \text{if} \quad r > 0 \\
        0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
    \end{array}
    \right.
\end{align}
```

The `split` environment should do what I want but I haven't found away
around the error `! Extra }, or forgotten \right.`.
It has something to do with `\left\{` and `\right.`.

```
\begin{align}
    E(r) &=
    \left\{
    \begin{split}
        \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2} & \quad \text{if} \quad r > 0 \\
        0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
    \end{split}
    \right.
\end{align}
```

Comment: since you are using amsmath you can use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac` to keep the fractions set in display style.

Comment: `\dfrac` works good as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a perfect job for `dcases` from the [`mathtools`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathtools) package, which loads and extends the `amsmath` package.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
    E(r) =
    \begin{dcases}
        \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2} & \quad \text{if} \quad r > 0 \\
        0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
    \end{dcases}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @user24328 you're very welcome :) happy to help. Welcome to the group!